# PHP зависает консольный скрипт, помогите найти причину!

Tags: php, shell

На моем сайте пользователи запускают "долгие" скрипты с помощью

```
exec ( '/usr/bin/php /var/www/script.php' );
```

Скрипт обрабатывает (загружает, читает, выгружает) файлы, обычно это достаточно большое количество. Отдельные экземпляры могут выполняться несколько часов без остановки.
Все прекрасно работает на протяжении **нескольких лет**. Да, это действительно так, последних года два никаких правок в код, или в настройки сервера не производилось.

Вдруг, последние пару дней начинает наблюдаться непонятная проблема - некоторые экземпляры запущенных скриптов просто зависают (или останавливаются вообще). Никакой логики не прослеживается, просто работа прерывается. Может в первую минуту, может спустя два часа.
Пользователей на сайте много, жалоб за последние дни - огромное количество.
В логах найти ничего не удается, учитывая что скрипт работает консольно - их и найти практически нереально. Грешил на curl, на mysql, мониторил два дня эту часть - ничего.
Пишет пользователь с жалобой на зависший скрипт. Беру его и запускаю через шелл, чтобы видеть весь вывод - в итоге он отрабатывает как швейцарские часы без единой ошибки.

Понимаю что вопрос в целом "ни о чем", тут скорее бубен нужен. Но я на грани паники уже, не знаю где искать.
Возможно кто-то направит на путь истинный?

ДОПОЛНЕНО.
Опытным путем установил, что скрипт видимо вылетает на таком участке кода:

```
sleep ( 1 );
```

То есть на какой то случайной интерации цикла все что sleep - выполняется, дальше - все, скрипт остановился. Как может sleep убивать скрипт, причем не постоянно, а в каких то отдельных случаях?

Сделал "ручное" логирование. В буквальном смысле скрипт выглядит так -

```
    <?php

while ()
{
    // Некие операции, логи включены, все ок
    mylog ( 'А теперь отправляемся на отдых!');
    sleep ( 1 );
    mylog ( 'Хватит отдыхать, продолжаем' );
}

?>
```

В логе расписано масса интераций, пока в какой то момент скрипт не умирает с последней записью в логе 'А теперь отправляемся на отдых!'

Изучаю проблемы, замеченные со sleep. Видимо я не первый, хотя информации и мало. Весь функционал скрипта уже отключил, он буквально гоняет по кругу цикл без смысловой нагрузки, только ради логирования. Иногда выполняет 2 тысячи интераций, иногда вылетает уже на 50-й

Может, какой то демон "убивает" выборочные процессы?

Comment: что-то не совсем ясно, как пользователи это запускают. В рамках хттп запроса это многочасовая штука делается. или что?

Comment: Нет, пользователь нажимает условное "Начать", в этом время выполняется указанный выше код, который запускает скрипт в фоне

Comment: может прояснить логгирование.

Comment: работа по нескольку часов - это в принципе ненормально. может быть что угодно, как то: бесконечно выполняемые в цикле тяжелые MySQL запросы, отсутствие места на жестком (их) дисках, недоступность URL запрашиваемых в цикле (не выставлен timeout CURL), отваливается соединение к базе, несколько десятков запущенных копий могут повесить сервак вообще, появляются зомби-процессы
логи решают

Comment: в идеале нужно отказаться от запуска юзерами таких скриптов, создать очередь и прогнозируемо обрабатывать задания с нужным лимитом

Comment: Сервер с огромным запасом мощности, памяти и дисков предостаточно, на протяжении нескольких лет все работает как часы повторюсь. На CURL конечно можно грешить, попробую таймаут поставить и помонтиторить, хотя конкретно от курла ошибок в логах (вручную введенных) не наблюдается

Comment: >Пишет пользователь с жалобой на зависший скрипт. Беру его и запускаю через шелл,
разные права и разные пользователи, тестить нужно так как запускает юзер

Comment: запускаю под тем же пользователем

Comment: ннада код скрипта, иначе че гадать на кофейной гуще. sleep ни разу не был замечен в подлости

Comment: обновил  вопрос. удивительно, я наверное одним из первых буду

Comment: что делает mylog? Может он ждет пока файл освободится, занятый соседним скриптом?

Comment: mylog = file_put_contents ('log.txt', $text, FILE_APPEND);

Comment: Поток один, лог пишу только для одного пользователя - для себя. Сейчас скрипт прокрутил 1200 интераций без проблем, следом "вылетел" на 50-й, в одном и том же месте. Бред какой то

Comment: а на серваке точно пару тысяч зомби не висит? че там с LA

Comment: la средний ~10-15, это при условии 20 ядер (80 потоков)

Comment: Сейчас убрал фактически всю исполняемую часть для своего аккаунта, оставив по сути только цикл с паузой и логами. *цка, даже так зависает. Пытаюсь писать в лог все подряд через register_shotdown_function() - mysql, defined_vars, время выполнения, нигде ничего подозрительного. Просто отваливается и все... Может, смотреть в аппаратную часть уже? Может, какой то из дисков умирает?

Comment: диски стоит проверить