# Что останавливает PHP?

Tags: php, ubuntu, shell, консоль

В продолжение темы [PHP зависает консольный скрипт, помогите найти причину!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1491867/php-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83)

Отбросил все суждения о работе своего скрипта, и пошел иным методом.

Создал простейший скрипт

```
<?php
    
    if ( isset ( $_GET['run'] ) )
    {
        exec ( '/usr/bin/php /var/www/sr/data/www/1.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
        echo 'Runed!';
        exit;
    }
    
    # Просто скрипт который крашится
    
    for ( $i = 1; $i < 10000; $i++ )
    {
        sleep ( 1 );
        file_put_contents ( '/var/www/sr/data/www/1.txt', $i );
    }
    
    ?>
```

Запускаю его, открыв в браузере mysite/script.php?run, запуск успешный. Далее мониторю изменения в файле 1.txt. В моем случае один раз "посчитал" до 421, второй раз до 1054, больше не проверял - уже понятно, что ЧТО-ТО останавливает работу скрипта.

Сервер выделенный, версия PHP7.2, пробовал 8.1 - то же самое.

Помогите найти причину!

---

Дополнено: вывод Htop.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод dmesg
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142572/discussion-on-question-by-----php); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

поставьте

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

у php скриптов выставляется настройка продолжительности времени работы скрипта (причем для выполнении из консоли есть отдельная настройка). Если скрипт не успевает отработать за выставленное количество секунд - он отрубается.

На будущее - если вы не знаете какая ошибка привела к завершению скрипта - загляните в логи php или используйте try{}catch с записью файла, и таких вопросов у вас уже не будет

Comment: Как вы объясните, что время работы скрипта всегда разное — то 421, до 1054? Если бы причина была в set_time_limit, то время работы скрипта было бы всегда одинаковым, соответствующим установленному лимиту

Comment: Кроме того, автор вопроса уже пробовал и логи читать, и try-catch использовать — нигде ничего не написано

Comment: @Mcile к сожалению дело не в set_time_limit(0);, в режиме cgi лимитов по времени нет. Но справедливости ради скажу, что  в поисках причины и Set_time_limie(), и ignore_user_abort() в код я добавил, безрезультатно (

Answer (score 0):

Наше обсуждение перенесено в чат, но я всё же напишу здесь. Вчера я говорил, что запустил скрипт на своем сервере, но из-за `sleep` он выполнялся не мгновенно. Сегодня же я зашел на сервер и скрипт отработал корректно и до конца.

Пожалуй вынесу наиболее вероятные причины.

1. Авто-рестарт PHP-FPM, возможно у вас где то спрятан скрипт авторестарта, посмотрите, просмотрите скрипты автозагрузки. Авторестарты часто любят делать во избежание некоторых проблем, но они сулят десятки других проблем.
2. Таймаут, что маловероятно, так как у вас скрипт доходил до разных значений.
3. Возможно есть другой PHP код, который ломает PHP и он из-за этого "падает", из-за чего у вас прекращается работа PHP скрипта с циклом.
4. Лимит ОЗУ для PHP.

Опять же, если не докопаетесь до истины, переустановите ОС на сервере предварительно сделав бекап, так как на моем сервере всё отработало как и положено. (но у меня отключен таймаут и лимит ОЗУ под PHP - 16 ГБ).

Comment: Почему вас тоже не смущает segfault?

Comment: А ещё автор не использует PHP-FPM

Comment: @andreymal я не совсем знаком термином segfault в отношении PHP, так как не сталкивался с ним на практике. Но у автора его быть не должно. Касательно PHP-FPM, я запускал скрипт на сайта автора и в изначальном вопросе была речь про вывод в браузере :)

Comment: Тем не менее у автора он есть, увы

Comment: 1. PHP-FRM отсутствует на сервере. 2. Таймаут аналогично, скрипт выполняется в фоне, ограничений по времени нет 3. Другой код исключен - скрипт "отключается" в любом месте на сервере, на любом диске. Рукотворных программ, которые шарят по pid и убивают случайный тоже нет. 4. Память для php безлимит, всего на сервере 256гб озу, максимальная загрузка 3-5% с учетом большого количества пользователей. .. Вопрос переустановки видимо начинает назревать, хотя крайне этого не хочется. ПО на сервере настраивалось и оптимизировалось долгое время, пройти этот путь заново - непростая задача..

Comment: @СергейБелов поэтому стоит максимально автоматизировать настройку сервера с помощью какого-нибудь Ansible, чтобы переустановка с нуля (без учёта времени на закачку данных) занимала не дольше десяти минут)